# Bottle is not showing up clear in render mode

Tags: materials, uv

I know this has got to be the dumbest question ever --but why is my dang bottle not showing up right? Clear.. with the label I just learned how to apply.[image]

Comment: try adding more light, and also put a HDRI/skybox in world settings

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped your object?

Comment: Lighting or HDR does not help at all.  See image placed into a previous doc --the cazadores bottles right behind the black bottles are showing up correctly... Yes Sir.. it was UV wrapped.   Image: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/cazadores/untitled.png

Comment: Bottle is here if anyone feels like deconstructing it. http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/cazadores/Kimo_Bottle_Backup.blend

And here is the scene with the bottle in it showing that it still shows black even with good lighting / HDR background (Don't laugh at my scene set up  --I'm obviously a total novice :)  http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/cazadores/Kimo_Sabe_Stand2a_Silver.blend

Comment: When sharing a file please pack the textures along with it :)

Comment: Oops. Ok. By "pack" do you mean upload it with the blend file? Or is that a feature I click in Blender as in "Pack File" ...?  Anyways... the label is here: http://www./aworkofmarc.com/1/cazadores/azoth_front.png --thank you.

Comment: Ok. Back to the drawing board i guess. thank you.

Comment: @Marc If cegaton has solved your issue, please mark it as accepted for future visitors. See the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

[image]

Where the label is opaque and the rest of the bottle is transparent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a go and report back. Many thanks.

Comment: Blend file added to the answer

Comment: Hmm. Close. Getting there! The bottle shows up now clear, but with a black tint and the label size and transparency is correct... but no label.  

http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/cazadores/KimoBottle2.png --The blend file is same as before  http://aworkofmarc.com/1/cazadores/Kimo_Sabe_Stand2a_Silver.blend

Comment: UPDATE: I downloaded your file --thank you. I copied your nodes onto my bottle and added your lights --it showed up fine. So somehow the black tint and black label I am experiencing in my 'mistake' file... must be something having to do with my node set up --however when I compare my black bottle nodes to yours, everything is the same.  I am going to hunt the reason down if I can. And post my mistake. I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: The Diffuse shader was not plugged into the bottom green dot of the Mix Shader.

Comment: Once you plug that in it should work: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DOtK0.png to place the label and resize it use the mapping node.

Comment: I get such amazing help here -- Is there a place I can donate to this forum?  Please let me know.

Comment: I don't know about that, but in the meantime if the answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted. The virtual currency here is votes... see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote