# Label shows in texture view but not in render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor

can anyone tell me why a label texture might not show up in a render (full render or viewport preview render), whilst it seems completely fine in the texture/material viewport?

I followed a tutorial for this in another project and did it successfully yesterday and have copied the nodes from there exactly / followed the tutorial again. But I cannot seem to find what might be missing.

I am using cycles. There is light in the scene, the viewport seems to have the UV mapped correctly. It is not mapped to the inside of the bottle. I have recalculated normals. I have used File -> External Data -> Find Missing Files. I have reloaded / saved the texture file as a different name and mapped it anew.
[image]

Print: http://prntscr.com/g0p9la

Thanks

Comment: Look at the colors of the nodes, green should connect to green, yellow to yellow and so on. You are connecting a texture to a mix shader that is not going to work.  The image should be connected to one of the color input of a shader.

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Comment: To have an image's alpha channel control the mix of two shaders readL https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: Or https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38351/1853

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to read! Thanks for the speedy and informative reply. Result: http://prntscr.com/g0q2rw